# mod_rewrite /foo to index.php/foo and /foo/foo2 to index.php/foo/foo2

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite

```
http://www.example.com/foo
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/index.php/foo
```

internaly.

But uris like

```
http://www.example.com/foo/foo2
```

should work, too!

I am not quiet good in mod_rewrite so please help me :)

Comment: Should `http://www.example.com/foo/foo2` be forwarded to `http://www.example.com/index.php/foo/foo2`?

Comment: no just an internal redirect w/ mod_rewrite :)

Comment: my bad, wrong choice of words. But you still want `/foo/foo2` to be `/index.php/foo/foo2` **internally** right?

Comment: yes. `http://www.example.com/$1` should be redirected internally to `http://www.example.com/index.php/$1`.

Comment: @Shiki if you know the answer please help me. i have still that problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

In `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

If this is the `index.php`:

```
<?php

var_dump($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL']);
```

Accessing `"http://www.example.com/foo"`, the result would be:

```
string(4) "/foo"
```

And `"http://www.example.com/foo/foo2"` would be:

```
string(9) "/foo/foo2"
```

Comment: got a working script already. Used "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]". But thanks.